# PHP to change some content of a HTML file

Tags: php, html, regex, string

I have a HTML file, which contains many `href=""`, `src=""` attributes, and I need to use PHP to read in the whole HTML file, then use PHP code to replace all the value of `href=""`, `src=""` to the ones I want. I think the steps are:

1. use `file_get_contents()` to read the `abc.html` file and save it into a variable
2. About the `href=""`, `src=""` value replacing part, is it better to use string replace functions or use regular expression?
3. echo the final variable(the updated HTML).

Comment: Use Simple PHP HTML DOM http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: str_replace will be faster, but depends on how complicated your replacement is.  Replacing href="mypage.php" to href="/newdir/mypage.php" is easy, but href="/one-of-a-number-of-directories/mypage.php" would be for regexes.  You might find using PHP to insert a base href tag would achieve the result you're looking for too.

Answer (score -1):

I'd use MVC model and renderer functions. For example:
**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><?=$title; ?></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3><?=$text; ?></h3>
    </body>
</html>
```

Than I'll have PHP array that contains those variables:

```
$array = array("title"=>"Mypage", "text"=>"Mytext");
```

Now we will use both in renderer function

```
function renderer($path, $array)
{
    extract($array);
    include_once("$path.php");
} 
renderer("index", $array);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
define('TEMPLATE', __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'index.html');

$template = file_get_contents(TEMPLATE);

$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = '/href="(.{0,})"/';
$patterns[1] = '/src="(.{0,})"/';

$replacements = array();
$replacements[0] = 'href="link"';
$replacements[1] = 'src="src"';


$template = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $template);

echo $template;
```

File index.html currently on same directory with PHP script. You can specify path to file modifying constant. In paterns/replacement array you can add any other paterns